# what is HeadGestureManager and is there a way to use it?

Tags: android, google-glass, gesture, google-gdk

I am currently working on an app that tries to detect different head gestures. I have however noticed in the LogCat the following :

```
06-11 13:36:32.349: I/RunnableDetector(8406): Recognized gesture with detector: NUDGE Calling listener...
06-11 13:36:32.349: I/GlassSystemServer(8406): Detected head gesture: NUDGE

...
06-11 13:36:41.990: I/HeadGestureManager(8406): Unregistering listener: com.google.android.glass.server.SystemServerHub$4@41bd2328 for head gesture: NUDGE
```

it seems that Glass can already detect the NUDGE gesture, is there a way to utilize this through GDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't documented right now, so probably the feature wasn't ready yet.

So I guess trying: `HeadGestureManager hgm = new HeadGestureManager();` didn't give any autocomplete?

If not and you really want to experiment with this (since it looks like it is already there), you could always try using reflection.

A great blogpost on how to use reflection (imo, loads slow but worth it):
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203

Edit: also today (June 26th 2014) the preview version of Android L SDK is available, you should probably best download this and check if the new version of Android, maybe has the API's opened.

Comment: Thanks @Ferdau for telling me reflection. I will look in to that.

Comment: Edited comment after seeing the Android L SDK is available